# Spacing between flex items

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I use Wordpress && Bootstrap 4. I can't managed to make space between my flex-items :

[![Bad spacing][https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Elb.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Elb.png)

This problem appear when I change my ES6 fonction click.

Html Code :

```
<section class="d-flex flex-wrap mb-4 mx-3">
                    <!-- The Favorites loop -->

<article class="favorites-card d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 justify-content-between" data-url="http://wordpress-dev.fil.univ-lille1.fr/2020/05/03/burn-my-eyes/">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap box-shadow w-100 p-3">

    <!-- Vignette + étoile -->
    <div class="d-flex mb-1">
      <div class="d-none d-xl-block">
                  <img width="150" height="94" src="http://wordpress-dev.fil.univ-lille1.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/rob-320x200.jpg" class="rounded thumbnail-decoration mr-3 mb-3 wp-post-image" alt="">              </div>
      <h3 class="text-capitalize post-title mb-1">Burn My Eyes</h3>
      <strong class="ml-auto mb-2 text-warning"><i class="fas fa-star lead"></i></strong>
    </div>

    <!-- Le texte -->
    <div class="text-justify mb-2">
      En cette année 1994, le Thrash Metal n’est pas au sommet de sa forme. L’avènement du Death quelques années auparavant lui a porté un coup sévère et ce style a été un peu ringardisé par Morbid Angel, Pestilence et consorts. [...]    </div>

    <!-- le boutton -->
    <div class="d-flex mt-auto justify-content-end">
      <a class=" btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="http://wordpress-dev.fil.univ-lille1.fr/2020/05/03/burn-my-eyes/" role="button">Lire la suite</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</article>

<!-- X articles odd or even can be add in this favorites space -->                                                        

</section>
```

Before I changed my ES6 (without add an data attribut) I was look like this, like I want but I can't figure out how to make this, I am very bad In flexbox:

[![Good spacing][https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVtFf.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVtFf.png)

Comment: In the code, there is only one card while in the image there is 3 cards, right?

Comment: Yes it is a loop, its is to make posts shorter, you can copy and past <article></article> number of time you want to reproduce?

Comment: Ok. So, I see you're familiar with `justify-content-between` so you probably need to add it also to the parent of those 3 posts (the `section` element)

Comment: @MoshFeu it's exactly what I did, but don't work : 

Parent is :

```HTML
<section class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between mb-4">
````

Comment: Can you create a https://codesandbox.io/ that reproduce the issue (copy the output html + add the necessary dependencies)?

Comment: codesandbox seem busy, too many error @loading

Comment: Try to reproduce my DOM on Jsfiddle with bootstrap 4 but it doesn't have the same result.

Comment: The only way for me to help is to make a reproducible snippet then play with it until it's working. I would prefer you to do the preparation part :) Is your site a live?

Comment: @MoshFeu, not, behind a VPN

Comment: Sorry. I can't help you that way. If you can somehow reproduce the issue outside, I'll be happy to try to help..

Comment: @MoshFeu : https://jsfiddle.net/Boutmos/2b7mgxjo/3/

Don't know how to replace img by placeholder

Comment: Better with little CSS : https://jsfiddle.net/Boutmos/2b7mgxjo/6/

Comment: I see that now it has spaces, right? So you good?

Comment: @MoshFeu yes =) thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by adding on the parent `<section>` :

```
 <section class="d-flex flex-wrap mb-3 mx-n3">
```

On the `<Article>` :

```
<article class="favorites-card d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 m-3" data-url="http://....">
```

And creating a CSS class .favorites :

```
/* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .favorites-card {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .favorites-card {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
}

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .favorites-card {
    flex: 1 1 31%; /* that f....k 1% made all */
  }
}

/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .favorites-card {
    flex: 1 1 30%;
  }
}
```